# WCF Service Reference name comes out as contract's name (interface), instead of the actual service name...?

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2010

Allow me to explain a little better.

I have a VS2010 Solution, split into 2 projects: a WCF Web Service, and a Class Library that uses the Web Service.

The WCF Web Service is a simple logging service; namespace "LogService", service "LogService", contract "ILogService".

When you use the "Add Service Reference" utility that comes with VS2010 to add a reference to the WCF, into the consuming Class Library project, you will see that the tool correctly adds a reference to a Web Service that can be called through "LogService.LogServiceClient". No problem here.

Now, I have another Solution; this is also split into 2 projects: another WCF Web Service, and a Web Application that uses this new Web Service.

This particular Web Service provides operations performed on a database; namespace "BLService", service "BLService", contract "IBLService".

Using that very same "Add Service Reference" utility in this project, however, adds a reference whose client name is actually "BLService.IBLServiceClient". Please notice there is a "I" prepended to the service client class name. The utility seems to have decided it should use the contract's name, instead of the service's name, to create the service client class.

I don't understand why does the tool behave differently on both Solutions. I've tried checking everything I could from both, and I can't find no significative differences (to my knowledge, at least).

Do you people know why does this happen? What things should I check, and correct, in my Web project (or anywhere else in the solution) so this odd behavior does not happen anymore?

Comment: Any chance you have [ServiceBehavior(Name="IBLService")] on your BLService class or a [ServiceContract(Name="LogService")] on your ILogService interface?

Comment: Just checked. There is no [ServiceBehavior] in sight anywhere, and all [ServiceContract] attributes have no parameters at all.